# Problema al contar palabras de un texto

Tags: python

estoy tratando de hacer un programa el cual me cuente las palabras un texto que contiene 4 frases pero solo debe contar la palabra 1 vez por frase, lo que me sucede es que al contarlas me cuenta solo una vez la palabra. Como podría solucionar esto?

Adjunto el texto del cual tengo que hacer esa validación.

```
Podador que podas la parra, que parra podas?
Podas mi parra o tu parra podas?
Ni podo tu parra, ni mi parra podo,
que podo la parra de mi tio Bartolo que apodase tolo.
```

En mi caso me cuenta 1 veces "parra" lo cual debería de ser 4 veces. (no se cuentan las que estén repetidas en la misma frase)

Gracias.

Adjunto código.

```
def lim(x):
x=x.lower()
x=x.rstrip('?')
x=x.rstrip('.')
x=x.rstrip(',')
x=x.rstrip(':')
x=x.rstrip(';')
return x

a=open('discurso.txt','r')
palabras={}
for i in a:
  p=i.split()
  print(p)
  for j in p:
    for k in p:
        j=lim(j)
        if len(j)>4 and j!=k:
            if j not in palabras:
                palabras[j]=1
print(palabras)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leyendo tu código no logro entender qué tratas de hacer, pero creo que buscas algo así:

```
def lim(x):
    x=x.lower()
    x=x.rstrip('?')
    x=x.rstrip('.')
    x=x.rstrip(',')
    x=x.rstrip(':')
    x=x.rstrip(';')
    return x

a=open('discurso.txt','r')
palabras={}
for i in a:
    p=i.split()
    print(p)
    for j in range(len(p)):
        # limpio cada elemento: 
        # p[j] es la palabra y 
        # j su posición en la línea
        p[j]=lim(p[j])
        # p.index(p[j]) es la posición 
        # de la primera palabra que aparece en la línea
        # si no coinciden es que está repetida
        if p.index(p[j])==j and len(p[j])>4:
            try: 
                palabras[p[j]]+=1
            except:
                palabras[p[j]]=1
print(palabras)
```

Realmente no estás contando, te falta el `+=1`, sino que asignas un `1` a las palabras que se va encontrando con más de 4 caracteres. El `j!=k` tampoco funcionará como esperas, ¿qué pasaría si una palabra aparece tres veces en la misma línea?

Espero que esta sea la solución que buscas, el resultado que obtengo es:

```
{'podador': 1, 'podas': 2, 'parra': 4, 'bartolo': 1, 'apodase': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta solución usa expresiones regulares para extraer las palabras, eliminando los signos de puntuación. Lo hace definiendo un patrón con captura `([a-zA-Z]{5,})` que reconoce sólo palabras de cinco letras o más.

Este patrón lo compilamos

```
patron = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]{5,)")
```

y luego lo usamos para separar una frase en sus palabras:

```
patron.findall(frase)]
```

Eso produce una lista de palabras con repeticiones y mayúsculas/minúsculas. Usamos compresión de listas para convertir todo a minúsculas y luego construimos un `set` para eliminar los duplicados de cada frase:

```
palabras = set([x.lower() for x in patron.findall(frase)])
```

Luego nos queda recorrer la lista `palabras` y actualizar los contadores. Para eso usamos un `defaultdict`. Es igual que un diccionario estándar, sólo que crea automáticamente la entrada cuando la llave no existe.

Este diccionario usa por llave la palabra y lleva la cuenta de cuantas veces aparece en total:

```
for pal in palabras:
    cuenta[pal] += 1
```

Resumiendo, el código completo es:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
patron = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]{5,})")

cuenta = defaultdict(int)
with open("palabras.txt", "r") as archivo:
    for frase in archivo:
        palabras = set([x.lower() for x in patron.findall(frase)])
        for pal in palabras:
            cuenta[pal] += 1
            
for k, v in cuenta.items():
    print(k, v)
```

produce:

```
podador 1
parra 4
podas 2
apodase 1
bartolo 1
```